# switch between two Form in C#?

Tags: c#, forms

I have two forms: Form1 and Form2. Form1 have button1 and Form2 have button2. 
When project is running, Form1 is displayed, and I click button1 then Form2 is displayed and form1 is hided. And if I click button2 then Form1 is visiable and Form2 is closed!

Form1:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }


    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Hide();
        Form2 fo = new Form2();
        fo.Visible = true;
    }


}
```

Form2:

public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form1 f1 = new Form1();
        f1.Visible = true;
        this.Close();
    }


}
```

Comment: And what's the problem?

Comment: what code have you written on Form2 button2 click event..Pls share us the same.

Answer (score 0):

```
void Button1_Click(...)
{
   Form2 f2=new Form2(form1);
   f2.ShowDialog();
   form2.Hide();
}

void Button2_Click(...)
{
   this.Hide();
   form1.Show();
}
```

Comment: ShowDialog is a blocking call, that's not what is pretended.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming Form1 is the "startup form" passed to Application.Run() in program.cs:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Hide();

        foreach (Form frm in Application.OpenForms)
        {
            if (frm is Form2)
            {
                frm.Show();
                return;
            }
        }

        Form2 f2 = new Form2();
        f2.Show();
    }

}
```

With:

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Hide();

        foreach (Form frm in Application.OpenForms)
        {
            if (frm is Form1)
            {
                frm.Show();
                return;
            }
        }
    }

}
```